# How to delete a certain object from your list in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a **subscribers** table :

[image]

---

When I click on **delete** btn will bring a modal to confirm :

[image]

I'm very close, but when I hit delete, it keep delete the last one on the list even if I'm not pressing the last **delete** btn.

---

I know that I have to use this `{!! Form::hidden('$id', $subscribe->id)!!}` somewhere, I'm just not sure where should I place it.

---

## Table

```
<?php $x = 0; ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <a href="subscribe/create" class="btn btn-sm btn-success "> <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Create </a><br><br>

        <table class="table">
            {{--Table Header--}}
            <thead class="thin-border-bottom">
                <th width="50" >#</th>
                <th width="200" >Email</th>
                <th width="100" >Subscribe On </th>
                <th width="100" >Delete </th>
            </thead>

            {{--Table Body--}}
            <tbody>


                <tr>
                    @foreach( $subscribes as $subscribe)

                    <?php $x = $x+1; ?>

                    <td>{{ $x }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $subscribe->email or '' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $subscribe->created_at or '' }}</td>

    

                    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_subscriber" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a></td>

                </tr>

                @endforeach

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

## Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete_subscriber" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class=" col-lg-5"> </div>
    <div class=" center col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::model($subscribe, array( 'route' => array('subscribe.destroy', $subscribe->id),'method' => 'DELETE')) !!}

        <hr style="height:300pt; visibility:hidden;" />

        {!! Form::submit ('Delete This Subscriber', array('class'=> 'btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block', 'data-rel'=>"tooltip" , 'title'=>"Are you sure ?", 'data-placement'=>"top"))!!}<br><br>

        <button data-rel="tooltip"  title="Go Back" data-placement="bottom"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" > Cancel </button> <br>

        {!! Form::hidden('$id', $subscribe->id)!!}

        {!! Form::close()!!}

    </div>
</div>
```

---

Can someone please show me, how can I delete the right one ?

**How can I stop my application to delete the last object in the list ?**

---

## Controller

```
public function destroy($id){

    $subscribe = Subscribe::find($id);

    $subscribe->delete();

    return Redirect::to('subscribe')
    ->with('success','The web directory was deleted succesfully!');

}
```

Comment: Can we see your controller?

Comment: give me response my code 100% work, if u stuck say

Comment: @Adnan : Your answer doesn't work with **Modal** which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and because I was in a hurry I had to bypass the problem by creating a new modal for every record inside the foreach loop in my view . I don't think that this is a sophisticated solution but in my case, where I expected a small number of records due to pagination, it worked fine. I suppose you could use Jquery to manipulate the modal action on every click but I couldn't make it work. Hope it helps

Comment: You should create dynamically id for each modal eg id="delete_subscriber{!!subscribe->id!!}" and at your table data target also as data-target="#delete_subscriber{!!subscribe->id!!}". That way you 'll create one modal for each record.

Comment: That's exactly, what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Just change like this, but check maybe i miss route path, and add your confirm popup

**View**
put this code in your foreach loop to generate delete button for every row and row item id

```
<td>
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'subscribe/' . $subscribe->id)) !!}
   {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') !!}
   {!! Form::submit('DELETE', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
</td>
```

**Controller** delete action

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $subscribe= subscribe::subscribe($id);
        $subscribe->delete();    
        return redirect('subscribe')->with(['flash_message' => 'successful delete!']);
    }
```

Comment: I'm testing your code now. I replace my `<td>` completely. I got `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php` I'm not sure why. I tried to debug it. Any ideas ?

Comment: hmm u can get that error because you POSTing to GET route.

Comment: if u have route resource "subscribe" this path must work

Comment: now u need to change your html code in tabel to be in same row play with it, then Form:submit('DELETE',...  with your         {!! Form::submit ('Delete This Subscriber', array('class'=> 'btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block', 'data-rel'=>"tooltip" , 'title'=>"Are you sure ?", 'data-placement'=>"top"))!!} to add confirmation popup combine that code....

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically set the id in the delete form each time a delete button is pushed so it knows which one to delete.

On the link which is opening a modal, add an `onclick` attribute which will handle this.  This should work for you.

```
<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_subscriber" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="$('#delete_subscriber').find('input[type=hidden]').val({{ $subscribe->id }})">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. Now, it won't delete and I got `TokenMismatchException` instead. Do I still need to use this `{!! Form::hidden('$id', $subscribe->id)!!}` somewhere ? If not, can I take it out ?

Comment: That is very surprising you got that exception now as all this should have done is update the hidden input field.  You do need that still so it gets passed to the controller so you know which one to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You only need in modal a form with reference at Controller@destroy, style it display inline to wrap a button submit inside in laravel 5.2 with method_field('DELETE') an crsf_field() add your bootstrap class or css :

```
          <form action="{{ action('UsersController@destroy', $user->id)}}" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('¿Seguro que deseas eliminar?')">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      </form>
```

The controller no have changes:

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    $user= user::find($id);
    $user-> delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
}
```